# Can I use two blendstates within one shader pass?

Tags: c++, shader, direct3d, hlsl, blending

I have code that sets a blend state, draws primitives, changes the blend state, and draws a second set.

This is all within one Present() pass, and while one vertex/shader pass is active, but on different rounds of Draw() calls.  So, it proceeds something like this:

```
SetBlendState(pd3dDevice, blendSolid);
DrawABunchofTrianglesThatMakeRedLines(pd3dDevice);
SetBlendState(pd3dDevice, blendAlpha);
DrawABunchofTrianglesThatMakeGreenLines(pd3dDevice);
```

If I take out the second SetBlendState, everything draws solid.  But with that one alpha-blending state set later, EVERYTHING is drawn with blending.

So, if you cannot change blending between Draw calls, what does need to be done to change the blending from one draw batch to the next?

I should note that in the VS Graphics debugger I can see both different blend states set in the two different draw calls.  Yet it still seems "last one wins".

Thanks!

Comment: Care to add a screenshot of the VS Graphics Debugger? There's certainly no problem with setting the blend state between draws; the last one won't 'win'.

Comment: Are you saying that when using the code above, the RedLines draw calls render with alpha blending instead of solid?